# How to calculate odds ratios for different combinations of categorical predictors in logistic regression?

Tags: regression, logistic, odds-ratio

My dataset has 3 variables:

- *outcome* - binary variable (0 / 1)
- *sex* - categorical variable (male / female)
- *colour* - categorical variable (red / yellow / green)

I have the following output from a logistic regression model which has *outcome* as the dependent variable and sex/colour as predictors (including an interaction):

```
Coefficients:
                      Estimate  Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)            0.12       0.11      1.09    0.276
colourRED             -0.07       0.15     -0.49    0.628
colourYELLOW          -0.02       0.15     -0.14    0.887
sexMALE               -0.07       0.16     -0.46    0.649
colourRED:sexmMALE     0.34       0.22      1.57    0.117
colourYELLOW:sexmMALE  0.14       0.22      0.66    0.510
```

I understand that the odds ratio for a RED FEMALE would be exp(-0.07) (reference: GREEN FEMALE), and that I could get 95% confidence intervals using the Wald method with the standard error of 0.15.

However, how would I calculate the odds ratio (including 95% Wald intervals) for a RED MALE (reference: RED FEMALE):

- Would the log odds be -0.07 + 0.34 = 0.27?
- How could I calculate the standard error for this estimate?

Comment: `reference: GREEN FEMALE` Did you mean "references: GREEN, FEMALE"? Reference category is selected for each factor (categorical predictor) individually.

Comment: Yes, correct I mean the references are GREEN and FEMALE

Comment: The log odds would be exp(-0.07)*exp(0.34). See a detailed explanation here: https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stata/seminars/deciphering-interactions-in-logistic-regression/

Comment: I think you mean the odds, but thank you. How about the standard error to calculate confidence intervals for the odds ratio?